# How to use Quarto extensions/templates in R?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, quarto

I am slowly making transition from Rmarkdown to Quarto. My questions is how to use quarto extensions like the following:

https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/quarto_templates.html

I installed it correctly, but what do next with it ?

How can I benefit from using those extensions ? Is it for ms word as well or only for pdf ?

Is there any function to list all extensions out that are installed and available ?
Do I need to install a quarto package in R or windows installer of quarto is enough for RStudio ?

How to change font and font size for ms word output ?
When I installed those extension I did not find it in "from template" in RStudio during new qmd file creation. Why is that ?

Thank you in advance.